# Как вывести ответ при клике наружу функции на js

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="btn">Go</button>

<script>

 let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

 let go = 0;

 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    go = 1;
    console.log(go); // 1

});


console.log(go); // 0
//Нужно чтобы выводился один

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не возможно. Потому что клик по кнопке и единица случатся потом, а последний лог случается сразу. Если нужна единица, то дальше код нужно писать внутри. Так работает асинхронный код.

Но если очень нужно писать это как обычно пишется синхронный код, то можно воспользоваться [асинхронными функциями](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await).

Лог сработает один раз после клика по кнопке:

```js
(async ()=>{
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  let go = 0;

  await new Promise( resolve => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', resolve );
  });
  
  go = 1;
  console.log(go);
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Go</button>
```

Comment: А могу ли я тогда экспортировать ответ внутри события click, на другую функцию (импортировать)

Comment: @KhasanAlimov нет. Можно только вызвать другую функцию из той, и при вызове передать аргумент, вот так: `someFunction( go );`. Но функция должна иметь этот параметр в её описании, вот так: `function someFunction( go ){ console.log(go) }`

Comment: Функции не работают если их не вызывать, поэтому между ними ничего нельзя импортировать/экспортировать. Они начинают работать в момент их вызова. Например `addEventListener` их вызывает во время клика.